# Is there any way to hide Probability field (Opportunity Object) from page layout without hiding it from profile level?

Tags: standard-field

I want to hide the probability field of opportunity object from a page layout. I can do this by from a profile level but I want to know is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Th fields which have a blue dot before them cannot be removed from the page layouts. The only way to remove such fields is by navigating to field level security.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lightning your could configure your opportunity pages showing only custom components with the fields you want and remove the details section.